# don`t succed in make one python file run another

Tags: python, file, tkinter, import

I am trying to make one python file run another only if the user choose that option, and every time it runs the another file no matter what happened.

I have two options:

- If the user chose option 1: the code needs to run SendMenu file.
- If the user chose option 2: the code needs to run **RecvimagesMenu** file
  but it doesn't work like I want, it opens the **SendMenu** file when I run the code.

Code:

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import Image, ImageTk
import SendMenu
import RecvimagesMenu

mGui = Tk()

def mhello():
    global v
    if(v.get() == 1): # if the user chose option 1
        mGui.destroy()
        SendMenu.run()
    if(v.get() == 2): # if the user chose option 2
        mGui.destroy()
        RecvimagesMenu.run()

    else: # if the user didn`t choose any option 
        print "5"

def Action():
    global v
    print (v.get())

def close(): # close the window
    exit()

def menu():
    global v
    v = IntVar()

    menubar = Menu(mGui)  # menu

    filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)  # menu works
    filemenu.add_command(label="Close", command=close)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

    mGui.geometry('450x300+500+300')
    mGui.title('Nir`s ScreenShare')

    canvas = Canvas(mGui, width=500, height=150)
    canvas.pack(pady = 10)
    pilImage = Image.open("logo5.png")
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)
    imagesprite = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=image, anchor="nw")
    Radiobutton(mGui, text="Share My Screen             ", variable=v, value=1, command = Action).pack(anchor=CENTER)
    Radiobutton(mGui, text="Watch Another`s Screen", variable=v, value=2, command = Action).pack(anchor=CENTER, pady = 7.5)

    mbutton = Button(mGui, text='Start', command=mhello).pack()  # button\

    mGui.config(menu=menubar)  # menu helper

    mGui.mainloop()

menu()
```

Comment: This code works as expected for me. Are you sure the problem isn't in `SendMenu` or `RecvimagesMenu`?

Comment: there is no problem in SendMenu or RecvimagesMenu, it just opens SendMenu file when i run it, i don`t know why.. it`s supposed to run mHello function just when the user hit the START button, maybe the problem is that i make "import SendMenu"/"import RecvimagesMenu"?

Comment: when i remove the imports from the code and run it, 
it shows me that its going to mhello fucntion just when the button START is pressed... 
but if i run it with the imports, it just start to run the first import (SendMenu) without waiting to the user`s choosing.. is it matter what files im trying to run? if there is problem with the file it doesn`t nee to run it without the command that run it.

Comment: That means you have module-level code. Importing a module runs all the code in it. You have to put all the code in the `run` function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is when you import your python file into the other one, it runs all of the code. Since you have not given the code for those 2 I can make an educated guess. You are not putting the code in those files into functions

```
for example: 
def printme( str ):
   print("str"
print"Hello world again"
```

If this was in a RecvimagesMenu.py as soon as you import the code it would print "Hello world again" and then you call `RecvimagesMenu.printme("hello world")` it would print the "Hello world".

In your file you also have code not in functions which is being executed right away. Either remove this code or move it into functions and call them.